# No such file or directory error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I would like to generate a pdf from my mobile application, but  When I run it appears to me as an error

> "E / Laura: /data/user/0/*/files/*/text_pdf.pdf (No such file or
> directory)" si "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
> virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream. close () 'on a null object
> reference "

and when I use the debugger I get `'this' is not available` as an error, and for File.separator I get `No executable code found`

where am I wrong? how can I fix the mistake?
I have this function in the Common class:

```
        public static String getAppPath(Context context){
            File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator
                    + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                    + File.separator
            );
    //        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Dir";
    //        File dir = new File(path);
            if(!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
    
            return dir.getPath()+File.separator;
        }
```

and I'm trying to use it in a fragment:

```
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_total_price, container, false);
    
            unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    
            init();
            initView();
            getBundle(getArguments());
    
            setInformation();
    
    
            Dexter.withActivity(getActivity())
                    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                            btn_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    createPDFFile(Common.getAppPath(getActivity()) + "test_pdf.pdf");
                                }
                            });
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
    
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
    
                        }
                    }).check();
    
    
            return itemView;
        }
    
        private void createPDFFile(String path) {
            if (new File(path).exists())
                new File(path).delete();
            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));
                document.open();
    
                document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                document.addCreationDate();
                document.addAuthor("Laura");
                document.addCreator("Laura");
    
                BaseColor colorAccent = new BaseColor(0, 153, 204, 255);
                float fontSize = 20.0f;
                float valueFontSize = 26.0f;
    
                BaseFont fontName = BaseFont.createFont("res/font/bellerose.ttf", "UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    
                Font titleFont = new Font(fontName, 36.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
                addNewItem(document, "Factura", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, titleFont);
    
                Font orderNumberFont = new Font(fontName, fontSize, Font.NORMAL, colorAccent);
                addNewItem(document, "Cabinet: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
    
                Font orderNumberValueFont = new Font(fontName, valueFontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
                addNewItem(document, txt_cabinet_name.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
    
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
    
                addLineSpace(document);
                addNewItem(document, "Detalii pacient", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, titleFont);
    
                addNewItem(document, "Pacient: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, txt_customer_name.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
                addNewItem(document, "Numar telefon: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, txt_customer_phone.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
                addLineSpace(document);
                addNewItem(document, "Detalii programare", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, titleFont);
    
    
                addNewItem(document, "Doctor: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, txt_doctor_name.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
    
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
                addNewItem(document, "Ora programarii: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, txt_time.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
                addNewItem(document, "Servicii suplimentare: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, servicesAdded.toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
                addLineSeparator(document);
    
                addNewItem(document, "Pret total: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberFont);
                addNewItem(document, txt_total_price.getText().toString(), Element.ALIGN_LEFT, orderNumberValueFont);
                document.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Succes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                printPDF();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Succes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        private void printPDF() {
            PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
            try {
                PrintDocumentAdapter printDocumentAdapter = new PdfDocumentAdaper(getActivity(), Common.getAppPath(getActivity()) + "text_pdf.pdf");
                printManager.print("Document", printDocumentAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Laura", ex.getMessage());
            }
    
        }
    
        private void addLineSeparator(Document document) throws DocumentException {
            LineSeparator lineSeparator = new LineSeparator();
            lineSeparator.setLineColor(new BaseColor(0, 0, 0, 68));
            addLineSpace(document);
            document.add(new Chunk(lineSeparator));
            addLineSpace(document);
        }
    
        private void addLineSpace(Document document) throws DocumentException {
            document.add(new Paragraph(""));
        }
    
        private void addNewItem(Document document, String text, int align, Font font) throws DocumentException {
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(text, font);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(chunk);
            paragraph.setAlignment(align);
            document.add(paragraph);
    
        }
    
    
    and this is the adapter:
    
    public class PdfDocumentAdaper extends PrintDocumentAdapter {
    
        Context context;
        String path;
    
        public PdfDocumentAdaper(Context context, String path) {
            this.context = context;
            this.path = path;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
            if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled())
                callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            else {
                PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("file name");
                builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                        .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
                        .build();
                callback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(), !newAttributes.equals(oldAttributes));
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            try {
                File file = new File(path);
                in = new FileInputStream(file);
                out = new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor());
    
                byte[] buff = new byte[16384];
                int size;
                while ((size = in.read(buff)) >= 0 && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    out.write(buff, 0, size);
                }
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onWriteCancelled();
                } else {
                    callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{PageRange.ALL_PAGES});
                }
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.onWriteFailed(e.getMessage());
                Log.e("Laura", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e("Laura", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What API level are you targeting?

Comment: `+ context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)` Please do not use such constructs while asking help here as we have no idea what string that would deliver.